# The `HTTP.IncomingMessage` of Node.js has the path traversal attack protection?

Tags: node.js, http, httprequest

For the testing of the **path traversal attack protection**, I have prepared the **SecredFile.png** file. Because it is out of the **public** directory, normally it could not be accessed.

[image]

Now try to access to this file by the REST client (the Chrome removes the `../`):

[image]

If to check the `url` property of the `request` ([HTTP.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage) type), it will be `/SecretFile.png`. Is it the the path traversal attack protection or no, the **URI has been changed** that is at least confusing thus could be the cause of the bugs.
Is such behavior fine?

Same result will be if we'll make the URL more complicated like `http://127.0.0.1/test/../../SecretFile.png` - the `request.url` will be `/SecretFile.png`

What I should to do developing the backend framework?

The related subquestion is, if the path traversal attack by `http://127.0.0.1/../SecretFile.png` or `http://127.0.0.1/test/../../SecretFile.png` is impossible, which path traversal attack protection measures I must to provide as the framework developer?

Answer (score 2):

Browsers and other HTTP client interpret `..` and `.` components in paths *before* they send the path to the server, so by the time it arrives there it's no longer an issue.

However, it's trivial to write something that does. Just open up a terminal, run `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` and type:

```
GET /../SecretFile.jpg HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.0
```

(end with an empty line to complete the request)

Some exploits (like path traversal in this case) can only be taken advantage of by doing things good HTTP clients wouldn't do.